# Location and GPS on API > 23

Tags: java, android, api, location, locationmanager

Hello I'm currently trying to implement an App where I want to track my GPS. 
This is my code but unfortunately it's not working with my current API I'm using.
I've found a few codes but this is only for Activities. I'm trying to implement this in a Service.

```
public class TrackGPS extends Service {

GPSInformation gpsInfo;


private LocationManager locationManager = null;
private String selectedProvider = null;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    selectedProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,true);
}



@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    SimpleDateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    Date date = new Date();
    String timestamp = isoFormat.format(date);

    gpsInfo = new GPSInformation();
    gpsInfo.setTimestamp(timestamp);


    if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
   //THIS IS WHERE IT STARTS CRASHING AND I GET AN ERROR I NEED PERMISSION

       Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(selectedProvider);


        if(lastKnownLocation != null) {
            gpsInfo.setLatitude(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude());
            gpsInfo.setLatitude(lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
            gpsInfo.setValid(1);
        } else {
         .........
        }

    } else {
       ...........
    }

    HttpRequestTask task = new HttpRequestTask(gpsInfo);
    task.execute();

    stopSelf();
    return START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


}
```

Comment: what exactly is not working? did you add the required permissions in the manifest? did the user allow permissions after installation?

Comment: In my manifest I have this:

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

Comment: An error accurs on the lastKnownLocation: Call requires permission which may be rejected by user

Comment: you need to request user permission, look at these examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37476445/android-requesting-runtime-permissions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44031624/android-location-runtime-permissions

Comment: It's for Activities only, I've tried it but I can't use it in my Service class??

Comment: Marshmallow and above need runtime permission for user to accept..

Comment: @ZeroOne can you help me with code examples to add it to my code?

Comment: you can guide the user to go to the settings, find your app there and give location permission

Comment: If i start my app on my smartphone I already have location permission but it's not working, the app crashes because of this line:
Location lastKnownLocation =    locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(selectedProvider);

Comment: note that the manifest permission is required at installation time, and the user/runtime permission is required after installation, either during the app usage or in the settings

Comment: @nandsito How am I supposed to get the permission after installation?

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6270602?hl=en#seeall